# JavaScript code for check the value of radio button (jQuery.val(); alternative)

Tags: javascript

I've two radio buttons to select a type of IVA:

```
<input type="radio" value="18" checked="true" name="ivacontract"> 18%
<input type="radio" value="16" name="ivacontract"> 16%
```

And I've one function that will calculate a value depending of the value of the radio button with name "ivacontract". In jQuery I'll use a selector and .val(); to get the value but this application (not coded by me) doesn't use jQuery so I don't know how to do it.

Any help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to I get the value of a radio button with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778206/how-to-i-get-the-value-of-a-radio-button-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getCheckedValues(objName)
    {   
        var arr = new Array();
        arr = document.getElementsByName(objName);

        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            var obj = document.getElementsByName(objName).item(i);

            if(obj.checked)
            {
                alert(obj.value);
            }
        }
    }

getCheckedValues("ivacontract");
```

Here is a working sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/eJBg9/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function checkradio(fname,rname)
{
    var radios=document[fname].elements[rname];
    for(var i=0;i<radios.length;i++)
    {
    if(radios[i].checked)
        return radios[i].value;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Where `fname` is your form name and `rname` is your radio buttons name that is in your code is `ivacontract`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Also, here is an example of getting and setting a value for the radio buttons.

http://www.somacon.com/p143.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" value="18" checked="true" name="ivacontract"> 18%
<input type="radio" id="radio2" value="16" name="ivacontract"> 16%


if (document.getElementById('radio1').checked==true) )
{
///   Your Code ///
}
```

Comment: Wat exactly is happening in your code. It seems very simple as well as tricky too. Can u please explain it. Thanks in Advance :P