# How to find the value of a radio button with pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input checked=checked type="radio" name="colors" value="red" />Red
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="green" />Green
<input type="radio" name="colors" value="blue" />Blue
```

Given the above, I set the red button to be selected by default (so I give it the `checked=checked` attribute. With this, if I ever call `.checked` on that input element, it will always return true, even if another option is selected.

In plain javascript (no jQuery), how can you get the actual selected option?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to I get the value of a radio button with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778206/how-to-i-get-the-value-of-a-radio-button-with-javascript)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
var options = document.getElementsByName("colors");
if (options) {
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if (options[i].checked){
             alert(options[i].value);
        }
    }
}
```

Would be **so** much easier with jQuery though... just saying.

Comment: this is basically what I am doing right now, but like I said, the .checked always returns true for the red input element, since it was explicitly set with checked=checked when it was created, even though another option was selected since then

Comment: Why are you defaulting the options to checked?

Comment: in this case, red needs to be checked by default. Is there another way around this maybe?

Answer (score 2):

plain javasript:

```
document.querySelector('input[name=colors]:checked').value;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will find it in the `document.all` collection:

```
var selectedColor = document.all["colors"];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this .....

This is example

```
<form name="frmRadio" method="post">
<input name="choice" value="1" type="radio" />1 
<input name="choice" value="2" type="radio" />2 
<input name="choice" value="3" type="radio" />3 
<input name="choice" value="4" type="radio" />4
</form>
```

function to get the selected value

```
<script language="JavaScript">

    function getRadioValue() {
        for (index=0; index < document.frmRadio.choice.length; index++) {
            if (document.frmRadio.choice[index].checked) {
                var radioValue = document.frmRadio.choice[index].value;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, they all have the same name. So naturally at least one of them has to be selected. Give them different ID's and try again.