# Making javascript check what radio form has been selected

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a dog race. 
Basically what I want is to check what radio the user checked, 
compare it to a random number between 1 - 5 and see if he won.

My question is... How do I compare them?

This is my code so far.

```
  function chooser(){
    var theDogs = ["dog1","dog2","dog3","dog4","dog5"],

     rand = theDogs[Math.floor(Math.random() * theDogs.length)];

    document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = rand;


if(pick == rand)
    {document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML =("win!");}
        else {
            document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML =("loose");
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<form id="pick" action="rand">
<input type="radio" name="dog" id="dog1">Dog1<br>
<input type="radio" name="dog" id="dog2">Dog2<br>
<input type="radio" name="dog" id="dog3">Dog3<br>
<input type="radio" name="dog" id="dog4">Dog4<br>
<input type="radio" name="dog" id="dog5">Dog5<br>
</form>

<br>
<br>
        <input type="submit" value="Gamble" onclick="chooser();">
<br>

<p id="winner"> </p>
```

Comment: What have you  tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A jQuery and Native JavaScript Approach. Take your pick.

```js
$("#submitjq").click(function() {
       var theDogs = ["dog1","dog2","dog3","dog4","dog5"],

       rand = theDogs[Math.floor(Math.random() * theDogs.length)];

      var pick = $("input[type=radio][name='dog']:checked").val();
      if(pick == rand)
      {
          $("#winner").html("jQuery: Won!");
      }
      else {
          $("#winner").html("jQuery: Lost!");
      }
});
  
document.getElementById('submitjs').onclick = function () {
   var theDogs = ["dog1","dog2","dog3","dog4","dog5"],

      rand = theDogs[Math.floor(Math.random() * theDogs.length)];

      var pick = document.pick.dog.value;
      console.log(pick);
      if(pick == rand)
      {
          document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = "JavaScript: Won!" ;
      }
      else {
          document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML =  "JavaScript: Lost!" ;
      }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="pick" name="pick" action="rand">
<input type="radio" name="dog" value="dog1">Dog1<br>
<input type="radio" name="dog" value="dog2">Dog2<br>
<input type="radio" name="dog" value="dog3">Dog3<br>
<input type="radio" name="dog" value="dog4">Dog4<br>
<input type="radio" name="dog" value="dog5">Dog5<br>
</form>

<br>
<br>
        <input type="submit" id="submitjs" value="Gamble Native JavaScript" />
        <input type="submit" id="submitjq" value="Gamble jQuery" />
<br>

<p id="winner"> </p>
```

Comment: Thank you, both your comments helped me out and I finally succeeded! Regards,

Comment: You should mark it as accepted so other users don't get confused and come to answer this question since this one did the job for you

Answer (score 0):

You need to give each radio button a value, and then `getElementsByName`, iterating through to find the one that's checked. [See similar thread...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986391/how-to-find-the-value-of-a-radio-button-with-pure-javascript)