# how to get checked radio button value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some set of radio button. I am trying to get checked radio button value using java script. But I got the error of uncaught id. I do the following code in html 5. I am not getting the value.

```
  function timeout()
  {
      if (document.getElementById["RadioButton1"].checked) 
         {
           choice = document.getElementById["RadioButton1"].value;
           alert('choice');

         }

     if (document.getElementById["RadioButton2"].checked)
        {
          choice = document.getElementById["RadioButton2"].value;
          alert('choice');
        }
     if (document.getElementById["RadioButton3"].checked)
       {
         choice = document.getElementById["RadioButton3"].value;
         alert('choice');

      }
    if (document.getElementById["RadioButton4"].checked)
      {
          choice = document.getElementById["RadioButton4"].value;
          alert('choice');
      }
   var c = document.getElementById("label1").value;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778206/how-to-i-get-the-value-of-a-radio-button-with-javascript

Comment: in that i not getting ans. thats why ask again

Comment: what you not getting?? cant you even see your mistakes der?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major problem visible from your code is a syntax error.

`document.getElementById` is a method and not an object, so you should call it with parens:

```
// --------------------v--------------v
document.getElementById("RadioButton1").value
```

Comment: I want text of selected radio button but i get  "RadioButton1" as a value which not my answer

Comment: <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="ans" AutoPostBack="True"   /><br/> <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" GroupName="ans" 
                    AutoPostBack="True" /><br />
             <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" GroupName="ans" 
                    AutoPostBack="True" /><br />
             <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton4" runat="server" GroupName="ans" 
                    AutoPostBack="True"   />

Comment: text of radio button is dynamically generated

Comment: @Ashishsiwalkar I am not expert in ASP but I can give you a hint. If you have rendered `<input type="radio" name="RadioButton" id="RadioButton1" value="RadioButton1">` and apply JavaScript `document.getElementById("RadioButton1").value`, you'll get `"RadioButton1"` since the value of your rendered element is exactly `"RadioButton1"`.

Comment: can i get the text of radio button

Comment: @Ashishsiwalkar Are you talking about the `<label>` element that is following your radio button?

Comment: @Ashishsiwalkar What is text if radio button? `<input type="radio">` element doesn't have text. It has name and value.

Comment: text is progarmatically generated. I used   RadioButton1.Text ="sdfdsf";

Comment: @Ashishsiwalkar As I said I am not expert in ASP. How this `Text` property is rendered in the HTML?

Answer (score 3):

If you use the same name(in same radio button group) for all radio buttons like this

```
<input type="radio" id="RadioButton1" name="radio_group" value="1"/>
<input type="radio" id="RadioButton2" name="radio_group" value="2"/>
<input type="radio" id="RadioButton3" name="radio_group" value="3"/>
```

you can get the selected(checked radio button value ) using jQuery,in one line.

```
var Val = $("input[name=radio_group]:checked").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

A set of radio buttons should all have the same name. So get the set, find the checked one and read its value:

```
function getValue(name) {
  var rbs = document.getElementsByName(name);

  for (var i=0, iLen=rbs.length, i<iLen; i++) {

    if (rbs[i].checked) {
      return rbs[i].value;
    }
  }
}
```

If the controls are in a form (which the usually are) and you have a reference to the form, you can get the set using:

```
var rbs = formRef[name];
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btnsubmit').click(function(){
          var result = $('input[type="radio"]:checked');
          if (result.length > 0) {
   $('#result').html(result.val()+" is Checked");
  }else{
   $('#result').html(" No radio button is Checked");
  }
        });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="gender"  value="Male"> Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"> Female
<input type="submit" id="btnsubmit" value="submit">
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: quit simple way and easy way implementation .

Comment: how we can implement same for checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

**This is ans for @yogi comment(
how we can implement same for checkboxes?**)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#btnsubmit').click(function(){
              var result = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
              if (result.length > 0) {
               var resultstring = result.length +"checkboxes checked <br>";
               result.each(function(){
                resultstring += $(this).val()+" <br>"; //append value to exsiting var
               });
       $('#result').html(resultstring);
      }else{
       $('#result').html(" No checkbox  is Checked");
      }
            });
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="skill"  value="Java"> Java
    <input type="checkbox" name="skill" value="Jquery"> Jquery
    <input type="checkbox" name="skill" value="PHP"> PHP
    <input type="submit" id="btnsubmit" value="submit">
    <div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: @yogi this ans for comment. Hope this will help you