# How do I properly validate the form using input radios?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, getelementbyid

I have a problem with validating the form in function validate() method. This line of code:

```
if(radios[i].value == "yes" && radios[i].checked == true) //DEBUG INFO: skips this step to else.
```

is being skipped because one or both of the conditions are false, but I'm not sure which one and as well as if the condition is proper to execute. I was thinking that radios[i].value == "yes" will correspond to the value attribute of that input radio button (In other words, the correct answer regarding that question).

When the submit button is clicked, I simply want javascript to tell me whether it's correct or not and to check if the radio button is checked.

Problem: I checked in the radio button, when submit button is clicked the alert for Please make sure you answer every question pops up 3 times and after that displays that I have the correct answer.

Here's the full code:

JavaScript:

```
// called when "Take Quiz" button is clicked
function takeQuiz()
{
// hide the intro
document.getElementById('intro').style.display = 'none';

// display the quiz
document.getElementById('message').style.overflow = 'auto';
document.getElementById('quiz').style.visibility = 'visible';
document.getElementById('gl_banner').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('gl_banner').style.visibility = 'visible';
}

//document.getElementById('submit').onclick = validateQuiz; //calls the function "validateQuiz" when submit button is clicked
// check for validation in the quiz
function validateQuiz()
{
var radios; // access elements by object name (DOM)
var i; // int variable
var right; // boolean variable to determine correct answer

radios = document.getElementById('question1').getElementsByTagName('input');
/*radios = document.getElementById('question2').getElementsByTagName('input');
radios = document.getElementById('question3').getElementsByTagName('input');
radios = document.getElementById('question4').getElementsByTagName('input');
radios = document.getElementById('question5').getElementsByTagName('input');*/

right = true;

// loop to check each radio button for validation
for(i = 0; i < radios.length; i++)
{
    if(radios[i].value == "yes" && radios[i].checked == true) //DEBUG INFO: skips this step to else.
    {
        right = true;
    }
    else if(radios[i].checked == false)
    {
        right = false;
        alert("Please check to make sure you have answered every question.");

    }
}

if(right)
{
    alert("You have answered correctly!");
}
else
{
    alert("Wrong answer");
}
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="message" style="overflow:hidden;"><div id="intro">Why not go ahead and take the quiz to test your knowledge based on what you've learned in Smartphone Photography.
            There are only 5 questions surrounding the content of this site.
            <br/>
            <button id="takeQuiz" type="button" name="name" onclick="takeQuiz()" style="cursor:pointer;">Take Quiz!</button></div>
            <div id="gl_banner" style="display:none; visibility:hidden;">Good Luck! :)</div>
                <form id="quiz" action="#" method="post" style="visibility:hidden;" autocomplete="off">
                    <!--QUIZ-->
                    <h3>1. How many percent of modern camera phones use CMOS?</h3>
                    <div id="question1">
                        <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-A" value="A" />
                        <label for="question-1-answers-A">A) 20%</label>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-B" value="B" />
                        <label for="question-1-answers-B">B) 80%</label>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-C" value="C" />
                        <label for="question-1-answers-C">C) 50%</label>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-D" value="yes" />
                        <label for="question-1-answers-D">D) 90%</label>
                    </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript selected radio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533138/javascript-selected-radio)

Answer (score 0):

**Edited for a pure javascript solution.

I got the function to get the select value from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778206/how-to-i-get-the-value-of-a-radio-button-with-javascript).

I don't think you need to do a loop here, as you only actually need to check one value- the value of the checked radio.

At the moment your looping through all the radios, so you'll always get three wrong answers.

**Edited again to fix some code errors.  I have tested the following, it is working for me.

```
function getRadioValue(name) {
var group = document.getElementsByName(name);

for (var i=0;i<group.length;i++) {
    if (group[i].checked) {
    return group[i].value;
    }
}

return '';
}

document.getElementById('submit').onclick = validateQuiz; //calls the function         "validateQuiz" when submit button is clicked

// check for validation in the quiz
function validateQuiz(){

right = true;
radio = getRadioValue("question-1-answers");

if(!radio.length) {
    right = false;
    alert("Please check to make sure you have answered every question.");
    return;
    }
if(radio == 'yes')
   {
    alert("You have answered correctly!");
}
else {
    right = false;
    alert("Wrong answer");
    }
}
```

Comment: radio = $("input[type='radio']["question-1-answers"]:checked").val(); is missing a ) argument it says. I have no idea how to use jquery.