# on button click show Radio button value is not working when radio value is changed

Tags: javascript, html

I am using following on button click inline javascript to show Radio button value. But it is `always showing English` even if i change the value

```
<input type="radio" name="LanguageSelect"  id="LanguageSelect" value="English" checked="checked">English &nbsp;&nbsp;

<input type="radio" name="LanguageSelect"  id="LanguageSelect" value="Tamil">Tamil &nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="LanguageSelect"  id="LanguageSelect" value="Hindi">Hindi</div><br>
<input type="button" class="button5" value="Continue" onclick="alert(document.getElementById('LanguageSelect').value);" />
```

**my requirement is, need to show which radio is selected !**

Comment: You have multiple elements that have the same `id` attribute. The DOM selector doesn't know which one to take.

Comment: @Lix : so how to make it workable ? i want to have same name as it will be useful when i post submit the values

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to I get the value of a radio button with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778206/how-to-i-get-the-value-of-a-radio-button-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the IDs of the element, and then depending on the value, show an element.

Otherwise, DOM cannot do that on itself.

### Solution

Remove the `id="LanguageSelect"` from the HTML, because even if some other is checked, the current element will still have the id property. Here is the example of your code:

[image]

Here is the fiddle where I tested your code: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/q25ba/

So, once you remove that, you'll get the problem fixed.

When you're selecting the value, it will look up for the first element, it will have the value of English, and will alert!

You can either use jQuery or check for the checkness of the elements:

#### jQuery

```
$('input[type=radio]:checked').val(); // check for the checked radio
```

This is easy and simple! I would recommend you this.

However, if you want to get the value of the radio buttons using JavaScript, try this:

#### JavaScript

```
/* this event to get triggered on click */
function checkCheckness () {
   var radioButton = document.getElementsByName("LanguageSelect");
   /* always remember, name should be similar, ID MUST NEVER be similar
    * using similar ID among different elements is illegal in HTML */
   if(radioButton[0].checked) {
      alert(radioButton[0].value);
   }
   /* add some else statements */
}
```

Comment: i want to have same name as it will be useful when i post submit the values

Comment: my requirement is, need to show which radio is selected ?

Comment: To have that, you need to use similar name not the similar ids..:)

Comment: You can see my answer! :) I have included everything that you need to know :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I did it myself.. please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you have only three options, the following solution would be reasonable:

```
<input type="radio" name="LanguageSelect"  id="LanguageSelect1" value="English" checked="checked">English &nbsp;&nbsp;

<input type="radio" name="LanguageSelect"  id="LanguageSelect2" value="Tamil">Tamil &nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="LanguageSelect"  id="LanguageSelect3" value="Hindi">Hindi</div><br>
<input type="button" class="button5" value="Continue" onclick="alertValue()" />
```

and then in a script define the `alertValue` function.

```
alertValue = function(){
    var language1 = document.getElementById('LanguageSelect1');
    var language2 = document.getElementById('LanguageSelect2');
    var language3 = document.getElementById('LanguageSelect3');

    if(language1.checked)
        alert(language1.value);
    if(language2.checked)
        alert(language2.value);
    if(language3.checked)
        alert(language3.value);
}
```

Check this one please [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybJrH/). I have tested there this solution.

If you don't have problem on selecting the elements with another way, then another approach would be the following:

```
<input type="radio" name="LanguageSelect"  id="LanguageSelect" value="English" checked="checked">English &nbsp;&nbsp;

<input type="radio" name="LanguageSelect"  id="LanguageSelect" value="Tamil">Tamil &nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="LanguageSelect"  id="LanguageSelect" value="Hindi">Hindi</div><br>
<input type="button" class="button5" value="Continue" onclick="alertValue()" />
```

and the corresponding js function:

```
alertValue = function(){
    var radios = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for (var i=0;i<radios.length;i++)
        if (radios[i].checked)
            alert(radios[i].value);

}
```

Check this one please [FiddleV2](http://jsfiddle.net/CbtGq/). I have tested there this solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
                    <input type="radio" name="LanguageSelect"  id="LanguageSelect" value="English" checked="checked">English &nbsp;&nbsp;

                    <input type="radio" name="LanguageSelect"  id="LanguageSelect" value="Tamil">Tamil &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="radio" name="LanguageSelect"  id="LanguageSelect" value="Hindi">Hindi</div><br>
                    <input type="button" class="button5" value="Continue" onclick="clickable()" />
```

```
                    function clickable(){

                    var val=document.querySelector('input[name="LanguageSelect"]:checked').value;

                    alert(val);
                    }
```

Answer (score -1):

i did it myself...

```
    onclick='if(document.getElementById(\'LanguageSelect1\').checked==true)
{alert(document.getElementById(\'LanguageSelect1\').value);} 
if(document.getElementById(\'LanguageSelect2\').checked==true)
{alert(document.getElementById(\'LanguageSelect2\').value);} 
if((document.getElementById(\'LanguageSelect3\').checked==true) 
{alert(document.getElementById(\'LanguageSelect3\').value);}'
```

Comment: Yes, only if you can include a `[]` parameter to check for each :) Then you'll be good as perfect...:) Something like: `if(document.getElementById('languageSelect1')[0].checked) {alert(this.value)}`...The usage of the `[0]` parameter is to check for each, you can use other integers too such as `[1]`, `[2]` to check next elements...